# TypeError - Cannot Read property 'AzureSubscriptionId' of undefined - unable to publish bot in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services, bot-framework-composer

Recently I was unable to publish my bot to Azure using publishing profile.

I was getting: `TypeError - Cannot Read property 'AzureSubscriptionId' of undefined` error.

The bot ran locally just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to incorrect LUIS prediction resource specified in my publishing profile:

```
"luisResource":"xxxxxx"
```

I'm posting it here since the error message was really unhelpful and it took me a while to troubleshoot!